# ¿Como puedo hacer que un dato de tipo date tome el valor de la fecha actual?

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo una variable que tiene que tomar el valor de la fecha actual cuando se elimine un registro y de esta manera guardar la fecha de des habilitación solo tomaría el día el mes y año

```
if($("#fecha_retiro").val() === ""){

    var hoy = new Date();
    var anio = hoy.setFullYear();
    var m = hoy.setMonth();


}
```

esto es lo que llevo

Comment: Con var date = new Date() no obtienes la fecha actual???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
if($("#fecha_retiro").val() === ""){
      var date = new Date();
      day = date.getDate();
      month = date.getMonth() + 1;
      year = date.getFullYear();
     $('#fecha_retiro').val(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
}
```

Comment: El alert muestra  NaN/NaN/NaN

Comment: Si quito el ($('#fecha_retiro').val()); me funciona pero no me lo guarda en la variable

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta para que mostrar como guardar los datos en la variable, espero que te sirva de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Tenés un error al querer obtener el año, estás seteando en vez de obtener dicho valor, entonces arrastrás el error y no te funciona.

Esto es lo que hacés:

```
var anio = hoy.setFullYear();
```

Esto es lo que deberías hacer:

```
var anio = hoy.getFullYear();
```

Quedando de la siguiente manera en lo que escribiste previamente:

```
if($("#fecha_retiro").val() === ""){
    var hoy = new Date();
    // obtenego el valor del año
    var anio = hoy.getFullYear();
    // obtenego el valor del mes
    var m = hoy.getMonth();
    // obtenego el valor del día
    var d = hoy.getDate();
}
```

Comment: ya logre conseguir los valores pero no se los he podido hacinar a la fecha_retiro